# Drop trigger if exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to execute a command similar to the following not inside a procedure but inside a simple sql file for mysql 5.xx

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME =  'tr_fnninio_censopersona_ins') THEN
    DROP TRIGGER tr_fnninio_censopersona_ins;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Why not just

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_fnninio_censopersona_ins;
```

[MySQL drop trigger doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html)

Comment: this still throws a warning which blows up my django migration. any ideas how to make it not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_fnninio_censopersona_ins;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_fnninio_censopersona_ins
    BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

         SET NEW.INSERTED= NOW();

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```